# Taking screen shot when soft assert fails using appium java

Tags: java, appium

I am new to automation. I want to take a screen shot when soft assert fails. I tried the code which is given [here](https://www.testingdocs.com/how-to-take-screen-shot-with-testng-when-an-assert-fails/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080761/how-to-take-a-screenshot-for-soft-assert-in-selenium-or-java). But I get error when I `@override onAssertFailure()`.

```
 @Override       //Here I get "Method does not override method from its superclass" error.
public void onAssertFailure(IAssert assertCommand, AssertionError ex) {
    // TakingScreen here
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) SetUp.driver)
            .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("AssertFailure_" + assertCommand.getMessage()+ ".jpg"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get following error:

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

and I cannot run my code.

Can anyone please, help me how can I proceed further.

Comment: What is the error/stack trace?

Comment: I get "Method does not override method from its superclass" error and I cannot run by code

Comment: I think the superclass has no method `inAssertFailure(IAssert, AssertionError)`...